# Ajax code not working when clicking my button

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm setting up a comment system and I'm using ajax to add and display the comments without refreshing the page, but the code that adds the comments doesn't work for me and I don't see any error, nothing changes when I click the button, can you tell me what's wrong?

i tried to change the  $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){ TO       $(document).on('click', 'submit', function() { and lot of changes but it's the same.

here's my code :
-the main page

````
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Add a comment</h3>

 <form action="" class="form-inline" id="comment_form" method="POST">

  <div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="commentaire" id="commentaire" cols="60" rows="10" 
     class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="ENVOYER" 
id="submit" name="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
<span id="comment_message"></span>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$.ajax({
url:"add_comment.php",
method:"POST",
data:{form_data,id}, 
dataType:"JSON",
success:function(data)
{
if(data.error != '')
{
 $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
 $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
 load_comment();
}
}
})
});
</script> ```
````

-the add_comment.php page :

```
<?php
require_once("../Ressources/Config.php");



$error = '';
$comment_content = '';
$id_user=$_SESSION['id_user'];
$id_produit=$_GET['id'];

if(empty($_POST["commentaire"]))
{
 $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Comment is required</p>';}
else
{
$comment_content = $_POST["commentaire"];
}

if($error == '')
{
$query =query(" INSERT INTO commentaires (id_produit, id_user, com, 
date_a) 
VALUES ($id_produit, $id_user, $comment_content, curdate()) ");
confirm($query);


$data = array(
'error'  => $error
);

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Where/how specifically does this fail?  This is an opportunity to start familiarizing yourself with debugging.  Take a look at the debugging tools in your browser.  Are there any errors on the development console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the information you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is it what you expect?  You can use the script debugger to place a breakpoint and step through each function as it executes and observe the runtime values of your variables.  When you do that, where specifically does it first deviate from what you expect?

Comment: $id_produit=$_GET['id']; should be $id_produit=$_POST['id']; because you send your data with POST.   data:{form_data,id},   looks also fishy it should look like data: {cpmmantaire: event.target.cpomment, id: id},

Comment: @David thank you for these informations, i just knew where the console is. i found two errors *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>* and *Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous* now i'm looking for solutions, if you know anything about thses errors please tell me and thank you again

Comment: @nbk thank you, but i still have problems in ajax that i need to solve first

Comment: you should also read on php and sql injection, because of your onsrt into and commemt

Comment: i think youz are missin <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in your websitcode

Comment: @nbk i used it, this is just part of the code, i'm still getting no response from ajax ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use XMLHTTP AJAX rather than jQuery...

Basically you would have something like this as your javascript:

```
function createRequestObject() {
var ro;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
    ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return ro;
}

 var http = createRequestObject();

function sndReq(action) {
http.open('get', 'rpc.php?action='+action+'&arg='+document.getElementByID('commentaire').value);
http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {
if(http.readyState == 4){
    var response = http.responseText;
    var update = new Array();

    if(response.indexOf('|' != -1)) {
        update = response.split('|');
        document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];
    }
 }
}
```

And you would use it by creating a "button" (aka a link )...

```
 <a class = "button" href="javascript:sndReq('foo')">Send Chat</a>
```

...and style it to look like a button.

```
.button {
font: bold 11px Arial;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
color: #333333;
padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-right: 1px solid #333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Then, to get your comment in your php file, simply do:

```
switch($_REQUEST['action']) {
case 'foo':
 $arg = $_REQUEST["arg"];
  /* do something with $arg (aka. the comment) */
  echo "foo|$arg";
  break;
}
```

and to display it in your chat, just create a div with the id = foo.

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
```